# What does 1+1≠0 mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I am using Schaum's outline of linear algebra in which there is a result that  the notion of alternating and skew-symmetric bilinear forms is equivalent provided that 1+1≠0, i.e a bilinear form f satisfying:
f(v,v)=0 satisfies f(u,v)=-f(v,u) and 
f(u,v)=-f(v,u) satisfies f(v,v)=0 
provided that 1+1≠0
I am confused with this sentence "1+1≠0"
Can anybody tell me what does it mean?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It means field is not characteristic $2$

Comment: Here, "$1$" is the field's multiplicative identity element and "$0$" is its additive identity element. If the field is $F$, it might be more recognizable to write them as "$1_F$" and "$0_F$" instead.

Comment: What is the use of these things in proving the two forms to be equivalent?

Comment: The use of proving that the two are equivalent, is that you now have one type of bilinear form with two characterizations, in stead of two different types of bilinear forms with each their own characterization.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working over the field $\mathbb F_2$, then you'll have $1+1=0$. More generally, the fields for which this equality holds are called fields with characteristic $2$. So, that book assumes that we are *not* working over such a field.